# Android App Works on Mobile Device But not on Tablet Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have an application which works on Mobile Device ,But when I run the same application on Tablet Device, I'm not able to see my layout file?

Note: Not getting any Error

Update:I define my layout XML file in Separate res>layout folders like

1) layout

2)layout-large

3)layout -small

and also resources in drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi, etc...

Update1:
AndriodManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.teluguone.torilt"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RAISED_THREAD_PRIORITY"></uses-permission>
     <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/> 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>    
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/trimg" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
     <activity android:name=".Splash"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LTActivity"

                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

         <service android:name=".MediaPlayerService"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.teluguone.torilt.MediaPlayerService" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

              <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
                  />

        <activity android:name="com.mdotm.android.ads.MdotmLandingPage"
                  android:label="MDOTM" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />\
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <meta-data android:value="ce9849662b9844468e942e4e3de6e2c8"
                    android:name="ADWHIRL_KEY"/>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Could any one Suggest a solution?

Comment: And what do you see instead? Do you have separate layout resources for bigger screen sizes? What's inside your Manifest? Provide more details on the issue.

Comment: @Egor updated ,please check?

Answer (score 0):

Too difficult to predict,however will say the possibilities.Whether you have added android:HardwareAccelerated="true" in activities? and for layout it's better to write some stuffs like

res/values-xlarge

```
<resources>
<bool name="Tablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

res/values

```
<resources>
<bool name="Tablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

boolean tabletDeviceSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.Tablet);

if (tabletDeviceSize) {

```
//use for tablet
```

} else {

```
//use for mobile
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
use
configration config = getresources().getconfiration();
if(config.smallestscreenwidthdp>=600dp){
setcontentview(R.layout.activity_main_tablet);
}else
{
setcontentview(R.activity.activity_main)
}
```